# Compress Video with FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, compression

I want to compress a 1 minute video in less than a minute on Android using ffmpeg in the best possible quality. But when the time is short, the quality is low and when the quality is good, it takes a long time to compress.
Do you know the right command?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved problem with this command

`ffmpeg -i innerPath -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -b:a 256k -vf -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac targetFilePath`

Comment: You have an orphaned `-vf` option which will result in an error: `Unable to find a suitable output format for '1.5M'`. Your command won't necessarily give you the "best possible quality": use `-crf` instead as shown in my answer.

Comment: when use i crf , the compression time very long

Answer (score 1):

For "best quality" at fastest encoding speed:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

- This assumes you want H.264 + AAC in MP4.
- If input audio is AAC add `-c:a copy`.
- If `-preset veryfast` is too slow use `-preset ultrafast`.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info and examples.

Comment: what will "-c:v" do?

Answer (score 1):

Compress video using FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -i videoPath -s 1280x720 -vf transpose=2 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 -b:v 150k -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec copy outputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG cannot do any magic....Low quality takes less time than better quality, so you have to choose right compromise between compression speed and video quality.

You didn't tell us what are size dimensions (WxH and Size in bytes) and neither current Audio and Video Codec (H264 or others).
For example 1 minute of 8K video takes more than 1 minute to be converted using HEVC codec using 10Mbps as bitrate, and cannot be reduced.....so.....